# Access query fields in mongodb inside forEach

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongojs

In mongodb, we can use forEach() on find() method for iterating over documents inside the collection . Now the question is can we access the query field inside the forEach . For eg:-

```
db.mycollection.find({name : 'Mike'}).forEach(function(document) {
    // var firstName = name;
})
```

Can we do something like this or what alternative we can use ? Please help.

Comment: The `find` method returns a cursor. The `forEach` iterates over the documents returned by the `find` method. The `document` variable can be used for example, print to the console: `printjson(document)` _or_ access a field: `let doc_id = document._id`. These apply to the query run from `mongo` shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there, try the below code:

```js
db.mycollection.find({name : 'Mike'}).forEach(function(document) {
    var firstName = document.name; // Just use the . operator
    print(firsName)
    // Rest of your operations.
})
```